# How to install Dillo in Lubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, 16.04, browser

How can I install Dillo under Lubuntu 16.04? Is there any `apt-get` repository?

Comment: @DavidFoerster A very lightweight browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Requirements

Ensure you have the **universe** repositories enabled via

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

or via the UI

[image]

## Installation

Update the local package information

```
sudo apt update
```

Install dillo finally via

```
sudo apt install dillo
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to use just `apt`. What is the difference between `apt` and `apt-get`?

Comment: They cover similar areas, apt-get has some parameters apt has not yet.So its not 1:1 the same at the current stage. I prefer apt if possible as it comes with colored output and it has a clearer structure for me. For details compare the man pages of apt & apt-get

Comment: Basically, apt is the somewhat more user-friendly front-end of apt-get.  They function basically the same

Comment: Ok, thanks to both of you for those explanations. @anonymous2